# Cannot get URL parameters with JavaScript on mobile

Tags: javascript, parameters

I'm writing a program that basically puts all user's buttons on a screen, exept the own user's buttons. I found some code to get url parameters, which looks like this:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return "";
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Now my program is written to add the buttons to all players screens, and that works fine. But for some reason, my parameter code cannot get parameters on my iphone or ipad, but it can on my computer. My parameters look like this:
`?username=User1`
When i run it con my computer with `getParameterByName('username')`, it returns `User1`. But on mobile. It just returns `null`. any tips?

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaScript function I use to retrieve URL parameters. It will return an associative array of values... you can also request a specific value.

```js
// demo function
console.clear();
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log('username:', getUrlParams("username"));
  console.log('all-params', getUrlParams());
});

// URL parameter function
getUrlParams = function (key) {
  var a = [],
    b = window.location.href
      .slice(window.location.href.indexOf("?") + 1)
      .split("&");
  b.every(function (c) {
    var p = c.split("="),
      d = {};
    if (p.length === 2) {
      d[p[0]] = p[1];
      if (key && key === p[0]) {
        a = p[1];
        return false;
      }
      a.push(d);
    }
  });
  return a.length > 0 ? (key && a[0] === key ? a[1] : a) : undefined;
};
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click me</button>
```

[EDIT] This code example will return "undefined" for both calls, because there is no URL parameters in the URL. Try this CodePen instead (look at your web console): https://codepen.io/cjboco/pen/MWwZbKO?editors=1010

[EDIT#2] Here's the expected results for your example:

```
Call: getURLParams("username")
Result: "User1"

Call: getURLParams()
Result: [{"username","User1"}]
```